# Merge columns and add values based on duplicate column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I have rows in my SQL Server that I would like to merge based on duplicate `StartDate` column. By merging, I would also like to

```
ID     CustomerID     Amount     PurchaseDate     TimeStamp
1      113            20         2015-10-01       0x0000000000029817
2      113            30         2015-10-01       0x0000000000029818
```

Based on the example above, I would like to have a single column where the values for the `Amount` column are summed up.

```
ID     CustomerID     Amount     PurchaseDate     TimeStamp
2      113            50         2015-10-01       0x0000000000029818
```

I'm not certain how I should go about this whether I should:

1. Create a new row with the new values or;
2. Update the latest added row and add the `Amount` to that row

But first I'd like to know how to get rows with duplicate `StartDate` column values

**UPDATE**: I have here a delete script for old values

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table GROUP BY CustomerID, PurchaseDate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest updating the last inserted;

```
UPDATE T
SET Amount = X.Amount
FROM Table T INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(ID), SUM(Amount)
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY CustomerID, PurchaseDate) X ON T.ID = X.ID)
```

In this case I'd suggest also to remove the old values

Comment: Hi, I currently have this script working. It does update the latest column to sum the amount. the problem I have now is delete all the other duplicate entries

Comment: You should get the highest ID grouping by customerid and purchasedate and delete all the rows having lower id and same customerid and purchasedate

Comment: @jmc Are you having difficulties in creating the script to remove old values?

Comment: I have create the scrip for deleting the old values, can you maybe perhaps check. I've updated the question